# Amortized Analysis for Re-sizing Array for Stack

Tags: algorithm, amortized-analysis

**Proposition** . In the resizing array implementation of Stack,
the average number of array accesses for any sequence of operations starting from
an empty data structure is constant in the worst case.

**Proof sketch**: For each push() that causes the array to grow ( say from size N to
size 2N), consider the `N/2 - 1` push() operations that most recently caused the
stack size to grow to k, for k from `N/2 + 2 to N`. Averaging the 4N array accesses to
grow the array with N/2 array accesses (one for each push), we get an average cost
of 9 array accesses per operation. Proving that the number of array accesses used by
any sequence of M operations is proportional to M is more intricate. 
(Algorithms 4th Edition Chapter 1.4)

I didn't understand the Proof Sketch Completely. Please help me in getting this understand.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is sort of amortized analysis where you charge requests like push() for work that isn't directly due to them, and then show that nobody has to pay too high a bill, which means that the average cost of work done is small.

In this case you have to copy the entire array when you run out of space, but you double the size when you do this, so you don't copy very often - e.g. at size 1, 2, 4, 8, 16... Here we bill each array copy to the push() operations which have been done since the last array copy. This means that if you do nothing but push() then each push() gets the bill only for the first array copy that occurs after it, so if the bill (split over a number of push() operations) is small per push() then the amortized cost is small.

If the array is of size N before it runs out of space and gets doubled in size then this article says this costs 4N operations, which sounds reasonable, and we don't care about constant factors much anyway. This gets split over all the operations since the last doubling. The last doubling was from size N/2 to size N so there are about N/2 of them. This gets you 4N ops split over N/2 push() operations so each push gets a shared bill of 8. Don't forget that a push() involves an array write whether or not it triggers a size-doubling and you get an average cost of 9 writes per push().

Comment: Makes sense, its the "(N/2) - 1" and "(N/2) + 2" in the original description I don't really understand though.